# Heroku "connection limit exceeded for non-superusers"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I am using free Heroku plan with shared database. Cedar stack, Rails 3.1.0.rc4.

When launching the application I constantly get this error, which breaks the process and which sometimes disappears after a random push:

> 2011-07-21T08:36:17+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with
>   command: `bundle exec rails server -p 11382 thin`
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]: => Booting Thin
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]: => Rails 3.1.0.rc4 application
>   starting in production on http://0.0.0.0:11382
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]: => Call with -d to detach
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]: => Ctrl-C to shutdown server
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]: Exiting
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:987:in
>   `initialize': FATAL:  connection limit exceeded for non-superusers
>   (PGError) 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:987:in`
>   new' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:987:in
>   `connect' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:260:in`
>   initialize' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in
>   `new' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter.rb:27:in`
>   postgresql_connection' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:292:in
>   `new_connection' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:302:in`
>   checkout_new_connection' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:254:in
>   `block (2 levels) in checkout' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:
>     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:250:in`
>   loop' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:250:in
>   `block in checkout' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /usr/local/lib/ruby/1.9.1/monitor.rb:201:in`mon_synchronize'
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:249:in
>   `checkout' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:151:in`
>   con
>
> 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:388:in
>   `retrieve_connection' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:107:in`
>   retrieve_connection' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:89:in
>   `connection' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/base.rb:704:in`
>   table_exists?' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_record/base.rb:789:in
>   `attribute_names' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:169:in`
>   _set_wrapper_defaults' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:129:in
>   `inherited' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/abstract_controller/railties/routes_helpers.rb:7:in`
>   block (2 levels) in with' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/actionpack-3.1.0.rc4/lib/action_controller/railties/paths.rb:7:in
>   `block (2 levels) in with' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/app/controllers/customers_controller.rb:1:in`'
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in
>   `require' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in`
>   block in require' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:225:in
>   `load_dependency' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:237:in`
>   require' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:344:in
>   `require_or_load' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:298:in`
>   depend_on' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.1.0.rc4/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:214:in
>   `require_dependency' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:399:in`
>   block (2 levels) in eager_load!' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00
>   app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:398:in
>   `each' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:398:in`
>   block in eager_load!' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:396:in
>   `each' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/engine.rb:396:in`
>   eager_load!' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in
>   `eager_load!' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/application/finisher.rb:51:in`
>   block in ' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:
>     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in
>   `instance_exec' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:25:in`
>   run' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:50:in
>   `block in run_initializers' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:
>     from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in`
>   each' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/initializable.rb:49:in
>   `run_initializers' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:  from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in`
>   initialize!' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:   from
>   /app/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.9.1/gems/railties-3.1.0.rc4/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in
>   `method_missing' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:    from
>   /app/config/environment.rb:5:in`'
>   2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 app[web.1]:     from /app/config.ru:4:in `block
>   in ' 2011-07-21T08:36:23+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited
>   2011-07-21T08:36:24+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting
>   to crashed 2011-07-21T08:36:24+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10 (App
>   crashed) -> GET  dyno= queue= wait= service=
>   status=503 bytes= 2011-07-21T08:36:25+00:00 heroku[router]: Error H10

I don't see any piece of my own code in this message.

Comment: Have you tried contacting heroku's support ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's a Postgresql error messsage that you get when you have more connections than specified in the `max_connections` setting in `postgresql.conf`. Unless you can change that yourself, you'll probably have to contact Heroku support.